# LS_DYNA_Family issue in VTK compilation in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, vtk

I am trying to compile in VTK5.10 in windows cygwin and I am receiving following error messages. Any resolution please:

```
 [ 27%] Built target vtkexoIIc
    [ 27%] Building CXX object Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/LSDynaFamily.cxx.o
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/VTK5.10.1/Utilities/LSDyna/LSDynaFamily.cxx: In function ‘int {anonymous}::LS_DYNA_STAT(const char*, {anonymous}::stat64&)’:
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/VTK5.10.1/Utilities/LSDyna/LSDynaFamily.cxx:44:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct {anonymous}::stat64’
       return stat64(fname,&s);
                             ^
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/VTK5.10.1/Utilities/LSDyna/LSDynaFamily.cxx:41:44: error: forward declaration of ‘struct {anonymous}::stat64’
     int LS_DYNA_STAT(const char* fname, struct stat64& s)
                                                ^
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/VTK5.10.1/Utilities/LSDyna/LSDynaFamily.cxx: In member function ‘int LSDynaFamily::ScanDatabaseDirectory()’:
    /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/VTK5.10.1/Utilities/LSDyna/LSDynaFamily.cxx:229:17: error: aggregate ‘{anonymous}::stat64 st’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
       struct stat64 st;
                     ^
    Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/LSDynaFamily.cxx.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/LSDynaFamily.cxx.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2418: recipe for target 'Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [Utilities/LSDyna/CMakeFiles/LSDyna.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I think the issue was with some if_else conditions related to some settings for other environments like POSIX, FreeBSD. I am not an expert so by hit and trial, I commented some lines in the file LSDynaFamily.cxx.

Line number 44:

```
//return stat64(fname,&s);
```

Part of line number 227 onwards was modified as below:

```
//#elif USE_STAT_64
  //struct stat64 st;

Part of line number 240:
#if defined (WIN32) && VTK_SIZEOF_ID_TYPE==8
  struct __stat64 st;
//#elif USE_STAT_64
  //struct stat64 st;
#else
  struct stat st;
#endif
  while ( tryAdapt >= 0 )
    {
    tmpFile = vtkLSGetFamilyFileName( this->DatabaseDirectory.c_str(),
                                      this->DatabaseBaseName,
                                      adaptLevel,
                                      filenum );
  /*  if ( LS_DYNA_STAT( tmpFile.c_str(), st) == 0 )
      {
      if ( adapted )
        {
        this->Adaptations.push_back( (int)this->Files.size() );
        adapted = false;
        }
      this->Files.push_back( tmpFile );
      this->FileSizes.push_back( st.st_size );
      this->FileAdaptLevels.push_back( adaptLevel );
      tryAdapt = 1;
      ++filenum;
      }
    else
      {*/
      --tryAdapt;
      ++adaptLevel;
      filenum = 0;
      adapted = true;
    //  }
    }
    return this->Files.size() == 0;
  }
```